# how to update table column based on ID match?

Tags: mysql

applicants.sql

```
full name | company Id    |      CompanyLabel
Johny Doe |     1         |    
Johny ben |     2         |
```

companylist.sql

```
companyid  | Company name     | CompanyLabel
1   | Starks Industry  | Starks Industry - New York
2   | Captain Industry | Captain Industry - Paris
```

the problem is I have:
5000 applicants who doesnt have CompanyLabel with 
1000 different company.

I'm using this to get CompanyLabel 1 by 1

```
UPDATE applicants set CompanyLabel = 'Starks Industry - New York' WHERE companyid = 1
```

How can I execute it all in just 1 query?

Comment: First of all, having Company name in applicants table means duplication of information as you obviously have that already in companylist. So my advice would be to normalize your database.

Comment: I just want to display it in list of records.

Comment: Sure, that is what the assignment is right now. But you should make an effort to understand why this is a bad database design, because if you design databases like this then you will have duplication of information which will lead to inconsistency! If Abhik's answer solved your problem, please mark it as solution to give him credit.

Comment: @MattiasLindberg that's what I have said but they wanted it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using join and update something as

```
update applicants a
join companylist c on c.companyid = a.companyid
set a.CompanyLabel = c.CompanyLabel
```